# Database table needed in different databases, how do I organise this?

Tags: database-design

I am sure this is a common problem, but I would be interested to know the best solution to this.
I have an employee table in my database, and I am sure I will need it in many other databases as well.
I do not want duplicate data all over the place. So how show I organise this? Should I have a company wide database as well?
I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One database is preferable to many duplicates. You can create a service layer for your applications to allow them to share the data easily or you can do it at the database level by linking data from different databases/servers (e.g. a "linked server" in Microsoft SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

One database. And for the details - The "Data Model Ressource book" has exact data structures for common problems (and guess what - yours is one of them) ;)

Comment: I intend to get hold of that book. When you say one database, do you mean for all applications, or one database for tables used in many applications. In other words, a single core database, plus specific databases for specific applications?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2008, Microsoft came out with a new "sofware" called Master Data Management.
For exemple, in your case, employee will be Master Datas they need to be unique in every database you will be using. It can be the same way with customers or providers, etc...

Master Datas are the datas that need to be unique organisationnaly wise. All the apps should count on it, CRM, ERP, and home made application.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/mds.aspx) is the link to the product.